# JavaFX get row and column from a GridPane

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make a hangman in JavaFX. I have 26 text nodes in a gridpane, but I don't want to make a method for each node, so I want to make a single method that handles on which text node you've clicked. I can't really figure out how to do it though. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that takes a `String` parameter representing the text on which the click occurred:

```
private GridPane grid ;
private int numColumns ;

private void processClick(String text) {
    // ...
}
```

and then just call it from each of the handlers, e.g.:

```
for (char c = 'A' ; c <= 'Z' ; c++) {
    String s = Character.toString(c);
    Text text = new Text(s);
    text.setOnMouseClicked(e -> processClick(s));
    grid.add(text, (c-'A') % numColumns, (c-'A') / numColumns);
}
```

(If you really need the row and column for whatever reason, you can equally easily make your method take those values and pass them from the handler.)